# Как проверить TextBox'ы на пустоту?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть Текстбоксы на форме мне нужно сделать проверку на ввод какого-либо текста.
Если все текстбоксы пустые, вывести сообщение, а если хотя бы на одном есть запись, выполнить действие.

Использовал данный код:

```
if(this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text)))  
{
  // TextBoxы пустые
}
```

но он работает если на всех текстбоксах есть запись, а мне нужно если хотя бы на одном.

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: `.Any()` - это "если **хотя бы один** объект подходит под условие". То есть по вашему условию `True` будет всегда, пока все элементы не будут заполнены. Если надо проверить, что бы "все текстбоксы пустые", то это уже `.All()` - он выдаст `True`, если **все** объекты подходят под указанное условие и если хотя бы один объект не подходит, то выдаст `False`.

Answer (score 0):

У вас логическая ошибка в коде. У вас сейчас идёт проверка на то, что хотя бы один из `TextBox`'ов пустой. Вам следует добавить отрицание в проверку:

```
// Если имеется хотя бы один TextBox с непустым свойством Text (пробелы не учитывать)
if (this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Text)))  
{
  // Сделать действие
}
```